# comment foreach binding vs foreach binding in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, templating, knockout-templating

In my HTML I can define these knockout foreach bindings:

```
<!-- ko foreach: customer -->
   <div data-bind="text: id" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

vs

```
<div data-bind="foreach: customer">
    <div data-bind="text: id" />
</div>
```

Where are the differences between those two approaches?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the word "better"? That's going to nudge this question closer to "subjective".

Comment: [Read Note 4](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

Comment: Thanks now I accelerated myself over 2000 points just for asking :P

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use native binding when a parent-child relationship exists within the binding section, like a ul and a li.

Use the comment syntax for containerless binding when your binding section does not have a parent-child relationship.

In your example you use the first code block because you are not trying to bind to a parent-child structure. All you want to do is just bind your customer data to a div, you shouldn't have to create a parent div and `foreach` through the customers and append another div inside of the parent div. It's more than you want to do.

**Good use of containerless binding**

```
<!-- ko foreach: customer -->
<section>
   <p data-bind="text: customer.name"></p>
   <p data-bind="text: customer.orderDate"></p>
</section>
<!-- /ko -->
```

However, if you have an **ordered list** you should use the **native binding** because it just makes sense.

**Native**

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: customer">
   <li data-bind="text: customer.name"></li>
</ol>
```

**Containerless**

```
<ol> 
   <!-- ko foreach: customer -->
       <li data-bind="text: customer.name"></li>
   <!-- /ko -->
</ol>
```

The second example just looks silly. You're adding more complexity for something that shouldn't be complicated.

Comment: I would add that containerless binding is the best solution to situations where you're limited in which elements you can actually add to a given container per the HTML spec.  For example, you have a tbody with a static row and then an observable array representing the dynamic rows, but the only valid child of a tbody is a tr element.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, you might want to duplicate a section of markup, but you don’t have any container element on which to put a foreach binding

To handle this, you can use the containerless control flow syntax, which is based on comment tags

Mode details on [The "foreach" binding, Note 4: Using foreach without a container element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)